# How to combine Redirect subdirectory to root and remove HTML extension at the same time using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried to combine Redirect subdirectory to root directory and remove .html using .htaccess

But I got a problem with my activity

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# RedirectMatch 301 ^/path/$ http://testdomain.com/
# RedirectMatch permanent ^/path/$ http://testdomain.com/
# RedirectMatch 301 ^/path/.*$ http://testdomain.com/
# RewriteRule ^path/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

I didn't have any problem with remove .html from the extension of the link and get the result

but I cannot get the subdirectory link in my root, I tried to clear # from the first 4 lines every time
but I didn't get a result

I nee do this like

```
http://testdomain.com/path/hello.html
to
http://testdomain.com/hello
```

Now with this code, I can remove the HTML extension and my link status is like

```
http://testdomain.com/path/hello.html
TO
http://testdomain.com/path/hello
```

Now I need to clear the "path" folder in my link

Meanwhile, I get the error 404 Not Found, please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your rule with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/path/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ path/$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Hi Sir, one question here, how did you get clue that `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/path/$1.html -f` condition in rule sir? Sorry if its a dummy question :) Thank you.

Comment: It is because OP wants to check presence of html file in `path/` subdirectory under `DocumentRoot` folder.